# PDAL filters.crop fails with Unable to transform crop geometry to point coordinate system

Tags: pdal

When trying to `crop` a point cloud using `bounds`following error is thrown:

`PDAL: filters.crop: Unable to transform crop geometry to point coordinate system.`

Below is my `JSON`:

```json
[
    "PointCloud.laz",
    {
            "type": "readers.las",
            "override_srs": "EPSG:32633",
            "filename": "PointCloud.laz"
    },
    {
        "type":"filters.crop",
        "a_srs": "EPSG:32633",
        "bounds":"([366977,367275], [5808263, 5808561])",
        "outside": false
    },
    {
        "type":"writers.las",
        "filename":"file-cropped.las"
    }
]
```

Below is the output of `pdal info` for the source point cloud.

```json
{
  "file_size": 19828816,
  "filename": "PointCloud_Potsdam_02_10.laz",
  "now": "2021-08-11T08:38:52+0200",
  "pdal_version": "2.3.0 (git-version: 0800a2)",
  "reader": "readers.las",
  "stats":
  {
    "bbox":
    {
      "native":
      {
        "bbox":
        {
          "maxx": 367276.48,
          "maxy": 5808562.58,
          "maxz": 71.07,
          "minx": 366976.53,
          "miny": 5808262.63,
          "minz": 33.23
        },
        "boundary": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 366976.53000000002794, 5808262.629999999888241, 33.23 ], [ 366976.53000000002794, 5808562.58, 33.23 ], [ 367276.479999999981374, 5808562.58, 71.07 ], [ 367276.479999999981374, 5808262.629999999888241, 71.07 ], [ 366976.53000000002794, 5808262.629999999888241, 33.23 ] ] ] }
      }
    },
    "statistic":
    [
      {
        "average": 367126.503,
        "count": 36000000,
        "maximum": 367276.48,
        "minimum": 366976.53,
        "name": "X",
        "position": 0,
        "stddev": 86.60253643,
        "variance": 7499.999316
      },
      {
        "average": 5808412.603,
        "count": 36000000,
        "maximum": 5808562.58,
        "minimum": 5808262.63,
        "name": "Y",
        "position": 1,
        "stddev": 86.60252485,
        "variance": 7499.997311
      },
      {
        "average": 45.74818685,
        "count": 36000000,
        "maximum": 71.07,
        "minimum": 33.23,
        "name": "Z",
        "position": 2,
        "stddev": 3.848459324,
        "variance": 14.81063917
      },
      {
        "average": 0,
        "count": 36000000,
        "maximum": 0,
        "minimum": 0,
        "name": "Intensity",
        "position": 3,
        "stddev": 0,
        "variance": 0
      },
      {
        "average": 1,
        "count": 36000000,
        "maximum": 1,
        "minimum": 1,
        "name": "ReturnNumber",
        "position": 4,
        "stddev": 0,
        "variance": 0
      },
      {
        "average": 1,
        "count": 36000000,
        "maximum": 1,
        "minimum": 1,
        "name": "NumberOfReturns",
        "position": 5,
        "stddev": 0,
        "variance": 0
      },
      {
        "average": 0,
        "count": 36000000,
        "maximum": 0,
        "minimum": 0,
        "name": "ScanDirectionFlag",
        "position": 6,
        "stddev": 0,
        "variance": 0
      },
      {
        "average": 0,
        "count": 36000000,
        "maximum": 0,
        "minimum": 0,
        "name": "EdgeOfFlightLine",
        "position": 7,
        "stddev": 0,
        "variance": 0
      },
      {
        "average": 0,
        "count": 36000000,
        "maximum": 0,
        "minimum": 0,
        "name": "Classification",
        "position": 8,
        "stddev": 0,
        "variance": 0
      },
      {
        "average": 0,
        "count": 36000000,
        "maximum": 0,
        "minimum": 0,
        "name": "ScanAngleRank",
        "position": 9,
        "stddev": 0,
        "variance": 0
      },
      {
        "average": 0,
        "count": 36000000,
        "maximum": 0,
        "minimum": 0,
        "name": "UserData",
        "position": 10,
        "stddev": 0,
        "variance": 0
      },
      {
        "average": 0,
        "count": 36000000,
        "maximum": 0,
        "minimum": 0,
        "name": "PointSourceId",
        "position": 11,
        "stddev": 0,
        "variance": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: _pdal info PointCloud.laz_ output would be welcome. It strikes me that the *spatialreference* option is not available among the [readers.las options](https://pdal.io/stages/readers.las.html#options), and maybe you are wanting to use *override_srs* instead? Also, it is the *bounds* option *ymin* parameter greater than the *ymax* one?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca Fixed the typos in `bounds` and also the `srs` parameter for reader.las. I also tried with `deafult_srs` and `override_srs` but the same error occurs.